# How add pagination on Criteria api using typedQuery?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, criteria-api

I am using Criteria API with pageable to return a `Page<MyClass>` with pageable, but when I insert `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` the query always returns 10 elements.

If I remove `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` from TypedQuery, my `typedQuery.getResultList()` returns all elements but obviously without pagination.

I have a service that calls my criteria sending my pageable for the main function `peopleRepository.filter`

```java
public Page<People> filtrarParcial(String name, String rg, String mom, String cpf, String nickname, Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize, List<String> sort) {
    List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by(orders));

    Page<People> listPeople = peopleRepository.filter(name, rg, mom, cpf, nickname, pageRequest);

    return listPeople;
}
```

My repository implements

```java
@Service
public class PeopleRepositoryImpl implements PeopleRepositoryQueries {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<People> filter(String name, String rg, String mom, String cpf, String nickname, Pageable pageable) {

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<People> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(People.class);

        Root<People> root = query.from(People.class);

        Path<String> nomePath = root.<String>get("name");

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if(!nome.equals("")) {
            Predicate nomeIgual = criteriaBuilder.like(nomePath, "%" +name.toUpperCase() + "%");
            predicates.add(nomeIgual);
        }

        query.where((Predicate[]) predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

        int paginaAtual = pageable.getPageNumber();
        int totalRegistrosPorPagina = pageable.getPageSize();
        int primeiroRegistro = paginaAtual * totalRegistrosPorPagina;

        TypedQuery<People> typedQuery = manager.createQuery(query);

//      typedQuery.setFirstResult(primeiroRegistro);
//      typedQuery.setMaxResults(totalRegistrosPorPagina);

        Integer totalRows = typedQuery.getResultList().size();

        Long total = totalRows.longValue();
        return new PageImpl<>(typedQuery.getResultList(), pageable, total);
    }
```

If I search for example a people with name **marcos**, `typedQuery.getResultList()` returns only 10 elements coincidentally with the same number elements by page (in my database there are 180). If I remove this

```java
typedQuery.setFirstResult(primeiroRegistro);
typedQuery.setMaxResults(totalRegistrosPorPagina);
```

then `typedQuery.getResultList()` returns 180 elements but with pagination, and all 180 elements are within single page without pagination

Comment: If you set the FirstResult and MaxResults the query should return maximum MaxResults elements (in your case 10). Page 0 -> elements 0 - 9, Page 1 -> elements 10 - 19 ... Page 17 -> elements 170 -> 179. FirstResult is the offset (0, 10 ... 170) and MaxResults  is the maximum number of elements per page.

Comment: Yes maximum elements by page, but show only this. I have in database 120 elements, and returns only 10 elements (totalelements) in json without other pages, if i try access ?page=1 doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the below configurations.

```
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<People> entity_ = countQuery.from(query.getResultType());
entity_.alias("entitySub"); //use the same alias in order to match the restrictions part and the selection part
countQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(entity_));
Predicate restriction = query.getRestriction();
if (restriction != null) {
    countQuery.where(restriction); // Copy restrictions
}
Long totalCount=entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();


query.setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset());
query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
List<People> result = query.getResultList();
return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(result,pageable, () -> totalCount);
```

Comment: Not sure if it was at the time of the original answer, but `PageableExecutionUtils` is now deprecated.  From what I can tell, this is going to pull every result back from the database in order to compute a count, rather than doing a `count(*)` type query.